# AWS StrongSwan IPSec Tunnel with Cisco fails during Phase 2 with TS_UNACCEPTABLE

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ipsec, strongswan, ikev2

I need to to setup a site-to-site IPSec tunnel with a vendor whom We need to access each other's API servers seating on the LANs using their respective Public IPs. We're using AWS, And I have configured a VPC with 2 subnets, and the Vendor is using CISCO ASA firewall.

I've been banging my head against the wall for some few weeks now but to no avail.

Here are the requirements:

```
      AWS Subnet 1     10.100.128.0/20        AWS Subnet 2
    [Our API server]-----------------------[Ubuntu/StrongSwan]---------[Vendors VPN Gw = 41.x.x.6]-----[Vendor's API Server=41.x.x.233]
          |                                       |
13.x.x.115/10.100.133.21               13.x.x.175/10.100.11.25
```

Here is what I've do so far

- I've updated routing table of Subnet 1 so that it's Gw is towards Ubuntu StrongSwan
- I've configured Ubuntu StrongSwan EC2 Instance to act as a NAT instance
- Stopped source/destination check
- Allow the kernel to forward through `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`
- Added Source NAT `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.100.133.21 -d 41.x.x.233 -j SNAT --to-source 13.x.x.115`
- Added Destination NAT `sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 13.x.x.115 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.100.133.21`
- Masquerade the rest of traffic from 10.100.128.0/20: `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.100.128.0/20 -j MASQUERADE`

Finally, I've setup the tunnel as follows

```bash
conn %default
        # Tunnel properties
        type=tunnel
        authby=psk
        auto=start
        keyexchange=ikev2
        mobike=no
        rekey=yes
        reauth=no
        compress=no

        # Session configuration
        ikelifetime=86400s
        lifetime=3600s
        dpdaction=restart
        closeaction=restart
        dpddelay=10s
        dpdtimeout=30
        # keyingtries=1

        # Default ph1
        # Encryption, hash and authentication
        ike=aes256-sha256-ecp256!

        # Default ph2
        # phase2=esp
        # phase2alg=aes256-sha256!
        # No pfs
        esp=aes256-sha256!


conn TigoPesa-Tunnel
        # Us
        left=%defaultroute
        leftid=10.100.11.25
        leftsubnet=13.x.x.115/32
        # Them
        right=41.x.x.6
        rightid=41.x.x.6
        rightsubnet=41.x.x.233/32
```

and configured PSK in the `ipsec.secrets` as:

```bash
10.100.133.21 41.x.x.6 : PSK "xxxx"
```

Whenever I try to bring the tunnel up, the following error always slap me on my face!

```bash
initiating IKE_SA TigoPesa-Tunnel[4] to 41.x.x.6
generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
sending packet: from 10.100.11.25[500] to 41.x.x.6[500] (272 bytes)
received packet: from 41.x.x.6[500] to 10.100.11.25[500] (447 bytes)
parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No V V N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) CERTREQ N(FRAG_SUP) V ]
received Cisco Delete Reason vendor ID
received Cisco Copyright (c) 2009 vendor ID
received FRAGMENTATION vendor ID
selected proposal: IKE:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/ECP_256
local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives
received 3 cert requests for an unknown ca
authentication of '10.100.11.25' (myself) with pre-shared key
establishing CHILD_SA TigoPesa-Tunnel{5}
generating IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi N(INIT_CONTACT) IDr AUTH SA TSi TSr N(EAP_ONLY) N(MSG_ID_SYN_SUP) ]
sending packet: from 10.100.11.25[4500] to 41.x.x.6[4500] (304 bytes)
received packet: from 41.x.x.6[4500] to 10.100.11.25[4500] (160 bytes)
parsed IKE_AUTH response 1 [ V IDr AUTH N(TS_UNACCEPT) ]
authentication of '41.x.x.6' with pre-shared key successful
IKE_SA TigoPesa-Tunnel[4] established between 10.100.11.25[10.100.11.25]...41.x.x.6[41.x.x.6]
scheduling rekeying in 85567s
maximum IKE_SA lifetime 86107s
received TS_UNACCEPTABLE notify, no CHILD_SA built
failed to establish CHILD_SA, keeping IKE_SA
establishing connection 'TigoPesa-Tunnel' failed
```

Someone, please save my day! (Background for the sake of communication, I'm not a network engineer, but a software engineer)

Comment: I searched for the core error "TS_UNACCEPTABLE notify no CHILD_SA" and found dozens of hits, and some suggestions how to resolve it. Have you been through search results and tried the suggestions you found? For example, there's one possible answer here https://community.cisco.com/t5/vpn/received-ts-unacceptable-notify-no-child-sa-built/td-p/4460240

Comment: @Tim Yes, I searched for the error "TS_UNACCEPTABLE notify no CHILD_SA", It is related to traffic selector issues. I even went through the thread on cisco's community, but it seems to hang without resolution.

Comment: I had a similar issue connecting to another Mobile Money VPN. My issue was the ``rightsubnet`` value. Please check with your partner on the subnets allowed by the CISCO ASA device.